# Set Field Value when importing CSV in Access

Tags: vba, csv, ms-access

I am importing thousands of CSV files using Access VBA and the Transfer Text Method. I need to add the file name or some format of it to the table to reflect the file that it came from. I already have the variable file name stored in order to import it. How do I append the code to reference the name of the "fil" variable?

```
With DoCmd
    .SetWarnings False
    For Each fil In fld.Files
        If UCase(Right(fil.Name, 3)) = "CSV" Then
            .TransferText acImportDelim, , DestTable, fil.Path, False



        End If

    Next
    .SetWarnings True
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
loopCounter = 1
With DoCmd
    .SetWarnings False
    For Each Fil In fld.Files
            'I'm assuming the new field that will hold the FileName
            'doesn't exist as part of the original table so we
            'are going to create it for the first file read in
        If loopCounter = 1 Then CurrentDb.Execute ("Alter Table MyTable Add Column MyNewField Text")

        If UCase(Right(Fil.Name, 3)) = "CSV" Then
            .TransferText acImportDelim, , DestTable, Fil.Path, False
            CurrentDb.Execute ("Update MyTable Set MyNewField = '" & Fil.Name & "' where MyNewField is null")
        End If

        loopCounter = loopCounter + 1
    Next
    .SetWarnings True
End With
```